# Redshift and luminosity

Tags: cosmology, redshift

Consider a flat FLRW Universe where the scale factor is $a = (t_0/t)^{2/(3+3w)}$. For a given redshift $z$, in which universe, $w=0$ or $w=1/3$ would a star appear brighter?

I am trying to solve this question and would like to know if I am heading in the right direction. So, I started off with the usual scale factor redshift relation $1+z=1/a(t)$ and for $w=0$, $a(t)=(t/t_0)^{2/3}$, thus $z+1=(t_0/t)^{2/3}$ and for $w=1/2$, $a(t)=(t/t_0)^{1/2}$, thus $z+1=(t_0/t)^{1/2}$ . Now how do I figure out in which case, the star would be brighter?